# Laravel ignores my PHP settings and times out

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel

I need to run a really slow PHP/MySQL script once, on my local server.
The problem is that Laravel times out after 60 seconds with the message "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded".

I have set

```
max_execution_time = 360
```

and

```
max_input_time = 360
```

in my `php.ini`. The settings are there (checked `phpinfo()`) but Laravel still times out after 60 seconds. Is there anything in Laravel that I can set as well?

Comment: Changed the correct php.ini file? use `phpInfo()` in your php script to see which `ini` file was used. It also shows `max_execution_time` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Laravel will override `PHP` settings. After changing the settings in your `ini` file, you have to restart the server to take effects.

So check whether you have restarted your server after the change in the settings

Comment: The server is restarted. I even rebooted the whole machine.